# KendoDropDownList default selected value not working properly on controller

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui

I'm having issues with DropDownList, i set the default value to it but when i send it to my controller come null. If i change the DropDownList manually it works.

This function create a new DropDownList

```
function alternarDropDown(e) {
    var data = [
        { text: "RESTRIÇÃO", value: "R" },
        { text: "PENALIZAÇÃO", value: "P" }
    ];
    var dropdown = $("#IndiceRestricaoPenalizacao");
    dropdown.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: data,
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        height: 100,
        change: onChange,
    }).data("kendoDropDownList").select(1);

    alert(dropdown[0].value);

    if (dropdown[0].value != "R") {
        var input = $("#VelocidadeRestricao");
        input[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

The alert show the correct selected value.

In my controller

```
public ActionResult CriarParamentrosAlarmeCBTC([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ParamentrosAlarmeCBTC alarme, int idAlarme)
    {
        try
        {
            if(TipoAlarmeBusiness.ValidarFaixaAlarmeCBTCJaExistente(alarme))
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "A faixa inserida já está cadastrada!");
            else
                TipoAlarmeBusiness.CriarParametroAlarmeCBTC(alarme, idAlarme);

            return Json(new[] { alarme }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);

            return Json(new[] { alarme }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
    }
```

`alarme.IndiceRestricaoPenalizacao` is null when i send with the default value.

I think `.data("kendoDropDownList").select(1)` was triggering the selected but it not works. So how do i trigger the default selected value?

Comment: Not exactly clear on what you are asking, but for binding it uses the html id of the input. So make sure $("#IndiceRestricaoPenalizacao") has an ID or Name attribute that corresponds to the model. Also, you may need to set [valuePrimitive](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/valueprimitive) to true.

Comment: The dropdownList only works when i select the value manually, if i send a post to controller without select it comes null. I have debug the js and its all ok and the default value is set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
var dropdown = $("#IndiceRestricaoPenalizacao");
dropdown.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: data,
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    height: 100,
    change: onChange
});

// set the dropdown value to your default value
$("#IndiceRestricaoPenalizacao").data('kendoDropDownList').value("R");
```

Another options is to set the value in your HttpGet. MVC will bind it automatically.